# What is the meaning of 疾風伝?

Tags: meaning

I am trying to understand the title of an anime series called: [Naruto Shippuden](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/NARUTO_-%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88-_%E7%96%BE%E9%A2%A8%E4%BC%9D). Searching google, I [found](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_shippuden_mean_in_Japanese) that `shippuden` can be translated as `hurricane chronicles` or `legend`. I looked for `hurricane` in the English wikipedia, and afterwards went to the [Japanese version](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%86%B1%E5%B8%AF%E4%BD%8E%E6%B0%97%E5%9C%A7).

> 熱帯低気圧（ねったいていきあつ、英: Tropical Cyclone）

Can someone explain why 疾風伝 whould be translated as `hurricane chronicles`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

疾風 (rapidly + wind)　means Hurricane (meteorological)
伝 means tradition/deliverance/legend
伝 is used like a suffix. For an Anime/Manga title it's o.K, but I doubt you would say it this way in normal conversation

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you doubt I would say in a normal conversation? 疾風伝?

Comment: Yeah. 疾風伝, with the 伝 suffix. It is more like written language.

Comment: ~~伝 is written language?? Then 龍馬伝/魏志倭人伝 are written language too? What would you say them in the spoken style then.

Comment: I don't know for sure. That's why I said I doubt. I can be wrong. But I see 伝 often in written language, but I don't hear it that often as a suffix. As I said I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Shippuden means hurricane because the name of the serie naruto shippuden and naruto's surname is uzumaki and that means hurricane.

Comment: Actually, Uzumaki means whirlpool not hurricane.